# Trouble Exporting Mesh with Decimate Modifier (keep UVs) to GLTF in Blender

Tags: modifiers, export, gltf

I am experiencing an issue with exporting a mesh to GLB format in Blender 4.0.1. The mesh has a Decimate: planar modifier applied with different Delimit options (position, normal, etc...), and it exports fine to GLB as long as I don't include the UVs.

However, when I added the UVs option, the export behaved as if there was no decimation at all, but in Blender, I saw that a lot of triangles were removed.

I "Apply" my modifier in the modifier tab. In the GLB export option, I also checked the "Apply Modifiers" box.

Comment: GLB does not support quads, that's why all faces (and therefore the UVs as well) get triangulated when exporting. And the mesh gets triangulated no matter if you include UVs or not. Only that the object has no UV map when you disable it on export and therefore does not show UVs when you re-import it.